# how to show product quantity in dropdwon on configurable products?

Tags: code, app

[image: qty is shown only in a text box but i want to sshow it in as a dropdown]My product quantity is showing in a dropdown but only on simple products.
I want to do the same on configurable products.

Comment: Can you please add some more details to your question.Thanks!

Comment: I have updated my question so you can understand it better.